# Flutter: BoxConstraints forces an infinite height, caused by Row Widget

Tags: flutter, widget

Oh what a nightmare these BoxConstraints are, please upskill me in anyway possible.

```
List<Chip> chipList = List.generate(toolsProvidedList.length, (index) {
  return Chip(
    label: SizedBox(height: 20.0, child: Text(toolsProvidedList[index]) ),
  );
});

  toolsProvided = Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: chipList,
  );
```

I've tried wrapped the Text child of my chipList in flexible, expanded, SizedBox, none of these have worked.  You can see I've used MainAxisSize.min on the Row widget.  That's not worked.

The Row needs to have a known height, how can I give it that?  I don't know how many chips there maybe, they may go across the row then, I hope, wrap down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure if I don't understand what you need...

But try this to see if that helps

(Remove your `Row` widget and replace it with a `Wrap`)

```
var toolsProvided = Container(
    child: Wrap(
      direction: Axis.horizontal,
      children: chipList
));
```

Adding an image or a better description would help.

Comment: Oh thankyou @encubos that's even better.  My solution threw a whole load of bottom padding into the mix, *HORRIBLE*.  So the Wrap widget is how you force a parent widget to WRAP it's child, PEEEERRRRFECT!  I salute you!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!  It's a list of items so intuitively one should reach for a ListView (doh).  But it complained about Bounds once more.  I think UI maybe one of the most knarly pieces of Flutter.

Here's the complete revised & working snippet.

```
  Widget toolsProvided = Flexible( child: ListView(
    children: List.generate(toolsProvidedList.length, (index) {
      return Chip(
        label: SizedBox(height: 20.0, child: Text(toolsProvidedList[index]) ),
      );
    }),
  ));
```

Happy days :)